# fetch object in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i need to convert my project from MySQL to MySQL I, i do fetch object in MySQL and its working but in MySQL I its not working

this code in MySQL (its working)

```
$sqlSelectSe = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM config");
 $FetchSe = mysql_fetch_object($sqlSelectSe);

  define("s_name",$FetchSe->s_name);
  define("s_url",$FetchSe->s_url);
  define("s_email",$FetchSe->s_email);
```

And This in MySQL I (NOT WORK)

```
   $sqlSelectSe = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM config");
   $FetchSe = mysql_fetch_object($sqlSelectSe);

   define("s_name",$FetchSe->s_name);
   define("s_url",$FetchSe->s_url);
   define("s_email",$FetchSe->s_email);
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`

Comment: i am new in learn in mysqli

Comment: `$FetchSe = mysqli_fetch_object( $conn, $sqlSelectSe );` ~ you need to suply the connection object and use `mysqli_*` for function calls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: @RamRaider .. $conn from where.!! from config.php?

Comment: presumably @mutaz - wherever you initially define your database connections - it may not be called $conn

Comment: thank you @RamRaider  . i'am try it but it's not work 

$FetchSe = mysqli_fetch_object( $Dbconnect, $sqlSelectSe );

Comment: Where are you defining $mysqli? Does it look something like this: `$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");`?

Comment: thank you @mark.hch yes but i do it in array  
$Db = array (
  "hostname"=>"localhost", 
  "dbname"=>"prstitodb",
  "dbuser"=>"root",
  "dbpass"=>"",
         );

   $Dbconnect = mysqli_connect($Db['hostname'],$Db['dbuser'],$Db['dbpass']) or die(mysqli_error());

   $DbSelect = mysqli_select_db($Dbconnect,$Db['dbname']) or die(mysqli_error($Dbconnect));
And its work

Comment: @mutazGhosheh ~ you need to use the connection object in the initial query too. Use error reporting when you are developing code and refer to your log files ( php log file specifically )

Comment: thank you @RamRaider i well use it now but its still not working
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "prstitodb");
$sqlSelectSe = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM config");
$FetchSe = mysqli_fetch_object($conn, $sqlSelectSe );

Comment: so close with your last comment - check @RamRaider 's answer. In your comment it would be `$conn->query` instead of `$mysqli->query` since you assigned your mysqli object to the `$conn` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the connection style I use for mysqli connections is as follows; hopefully you should be able to get your connection working if you do likewise. Try not to mix up procedural and OO style code ~ it will probably work but is bad practise and leads to bad habits.

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';
$conn   =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
```

I then prefer to use OO style notation in keeping with the initial connection, so a query to select records:

```
$sql='select * from users';
$results=$conn->query( $sql );
if( $results ){
    while( $rs=$results->fetch_object() ) echo $rs->username;/* etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you man  @RumRaider
and i solve it from another way

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prstitodb");
$sql="SELECT * FROM config";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
$FetchSe = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
```